# Magento2 how to rewrite block and extend the wishlist_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, integrate

In layout file,**wishlist_index_index.xml**,

```
 <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist"
    name="customer.wishlist" template="view.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

But when I Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront,

template is `magento2/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml` 
but the block is `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Interceptor`

I need to understand how achieved
Forgive my poor English

Answer (score 1):

you can simple rewrite block using `etc/di.xml` **`<preference>`** method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" type="Vendor\Package\Block\Customer\Wishlist"/>
</config>
```

Now you have to create Block file,

```
Vendor\Package\Block\Customer\Wishlist.php
```

Inside wishlist.php you can extend core wishlist block and do changes as per your requirements.

Remove var folder from root and check.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Before i ask this question, I try to use preference to extend Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist, but it didn't work.  This block has been rewritten, I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: plz show your full code to check more details, This is the basic step for intergration

Comment: In magento 2.0.7,This block has been rewritten. And i didn't found config in di.xml file.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> when I Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront,
>
> template is
>   `magento2/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml`
>   but the block is `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Interceptor`

If I understand you correctly, you are wondering why it's `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Interceptor` and not `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist` as defined in the XML.

This is not a bug. Interceptors are automatically generated when the class has a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) and **extend** the original class. So while the real type of the block is this interceptor, you can ignore the fact and treat it just as the original block.

Comment: But i did't find where does this plugin define in any di.xml. I want to add some function in template file(view.phtml)  corresponding block.I have tried to preference this block, but doesn'ts work.Thanksfor your help